# How to make paragraph draggable with Froala?

Tags: angular, froala

I am developing an Angular 7 app and am using Froala editor.
How can I make a paragraph (`<p>`) draggable in the same way an image is draggable? I tried to set it to draggable=true but only parts of it was moving (if I first selected it). How can I make the paragraph "hold together" and not split up when moving?

Comment: The selected text is draggable. So you can select the whole paragraph and drag it. That option is the most versatile, since you can make any part of the text draggable. It is also the way most text editors work, so the users should be familiar with that behavior.

Comment: Aha but it seems very instable when dragging text fragments, like it was a hack to do it that way. But is there not a way to make the whole paragraph draggable like a block of text? Like I drag around the image?

Comment: Not sure about that. Here are two more remarks that may help you: (1) I noticed that a triple-click selects the paragraph; (2) You could try turning off the [dragInline](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/options#dragInline) option, to force the drag/drop on block elements.

Comment: I tried to triple click and then move and that seems to work (most of the time). Thank you! Perhaps there is a way that the user don´t have to triple click to select?

Comment: You can drag any content but please check this: https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/examples/drag-inline. The draggable plugin will help you identify dragging by borders.